# Problem installing quick.db in npm for discord bot in discord.js

Tags: npm, discord.js, quick.db

-> I got this error while trying to install quick.db:
`https://pastebin.com/qHwyUxPe`

- I tried the troubleshooting on the documents:
  `https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md`
- I found some similar questions and follow the steps, but it still didn't solve the problems.
- The debug logs: `https://pastebin.com/BfJBdAQZ`

> Also I got no idea how did Python get involved in there (I use JS), maybe that's because I'm a beginner and I have no idea what I put inside the code :\

- Node Version: v17.0.1
- Node gyp Version: v8.2.0

Answer (score 0):

The logs you shared all seem to indicate that **Visual Studio** is not installed. Can you please verify that it is?

Note: It is important to notice the distinction between Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code. Despite the fact they have similar names, they are very different products and have different support for extensions/plugins. Visual Studio Code has a **blue** logo and functions exclusively as a code editor, while Visual Studio Code has a **purple** logo (images not attached because I don't have permission, but you can Google around) and functions as a complete IDE with integration into other Microsoft products.

**Plugins/extensions that work in Visual Studio will not always work in Visual Studio Code, and vice versa.** It is important to ensure you are using the right one.